# Bootstrap: text in columns - need to line them up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to do the following:

[image]

I have achieved this using the following code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="x" class="col-sm-2 control-label">TEXT</label>
        <div id="xDiv" class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="radio">Test 1</div>
            <div class="radio">Test 2</div>
            <div class="radio">Test 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it feels like a hack to use the radio class given there's no radio boxes.

Essentially, I just want the "TEXT" to line up with the first line "Test 1", with "Test 2" and "Test 3" appearing directly below it.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, that is a bit of a hack, you're using something designed for forms to make something display how you want. Kudos for wanting to find a better solution!

There are many ways you could do this depending on the context of what your text is showing.

### The Grid System

The first way is to just use [Bootstraps Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to place your content in two different columns. These will automatically line up, and you can even make the columns different widths (or make them expand to 100% width on small screens).

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Using Grid System</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"><p>TEXT</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><p>Test 1<br/>Test 2<br/>Test 3</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The disadvantage of this is that it is not particularly semantic, and screen readers may not read things in the order you expect.

### Tables

Option 2 is to use good old fashioned tables. If your data is suited to tables then use them! You don't have to use Bootstraps built in classes either, so you can style it how you want.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Using Tables</h2>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
            <table class="table">
               <tr>
                    <td>TEXT</td>
                    <td>Test 1<br/>Test 2<br/>Test 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The disadvantage of this is that if your data isn't suited to a table you shouldn't really use a table, as it's basically the same as what you were initially doing, abusing a html element just to make it style how you want.

### Description lists

The last option I can think of for now is to use the `<dl>` tag. This is a description list and [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl);

> The HTML  Element (or HTML Description List Element) encloses a
>   list of pairs of terms and descriptions. Common uses for this element
>   are to implement a glossary or to display metadata (a list of
>   key-value pairs).

Using these you can do this

```
  <h2>Using Description Lists</h2>

  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
      <dt>Text</dt>
      <dd>Test 1</dd>
      <dd>Test 2</dd>
      <dd>Test 3</dd>
   </dl>
```

In this example we are using a 'single term, multiple descriptions' approach. This assumes that Test 1, 2 and 3 and different descriptions of the term 'Text'. Again, using this element only makes sense if you truly are trying to show a list of descriptions, the same way a table should only really show tabular data.

There are many other possibilities I am sure, some probably simpler, but these are the three that sprung to mind that fit nicely in the Bootstrap framework and may make your code more semantic, which is always nice.

Comment: Your first example, except using `<p class="form-control-static">`, did the trick for me. Thanks.